# Populate NULL from existing value from another record

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm using ArcGIS Pro on the table below (ACCT_ID field is sorted). The goal is to calculate/populate the "Asset" field where if rows have the same "ACCT_ID" and at least one of these rows has "Asset" is not null, calculate the null Asset field(s) with the same Asset that has a matching ACCT_ID.
For example, for the four ACCT_IDs of 1976550000, calculate Asset to be 00070925 for the three remaining nulls.
Or for the two ACCT_IDs of 3988856629, calculate Asset 00146135 for the null record
Or for the two ACCT_IDs 366804000, leave Asset null.
I assume this is best done using field calculator but not sure how to go about it.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field calculator loops over records in order, so there's no way to know what the first `<Null>` should be for a given ID if a valid value hasn't been seen yet.  It would take two loops over the data, once to determine the mapping and then another to fill the nulls.  So this would be better suited to python cursors than the field calculator.

Here's a snippet as an example.  Has not been tested, so back up your data if necessary:

```
fc = r'C:\example.gdb\the_feature_class'
fields = ['ACCT_ID', 'Asset']
lookup = {}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for acct_id, asset in cursor:
        if asset:
            lookup[acct_id] = asset

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for acct_id, asset in cursor:
        if not asset:
            try:
                asset = lookup[acct_id]
            except KeyError:
                print('No asset for "{}"'.format(acct_id))
            else:
                cursor.updateRow([acct_id, asset])
```

This assumes one unique asset per acct_id.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple alternative approaches to what has already been put forward.

One approach is to loop through the table twice with a cursor, similar to [@mikewatt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/64255/mikewatt)'s [earlier answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/429359/196564), but to use the same cursor instead of two separate cursors.  Although an update cursor can update a table, it doesn't have to update a table, and resetting an existing cursor is both less code and can be more efficient than instantiating multiple cursors in certain situations.

```py
# modifying mikewatt code for demonstration

fc = # path to feature class or table
fields = ['ACCT_ID', 'Asset']
lookup = {}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for acct_id, asset in cursor:
        if asset:
            lookup[acct_id] = asset
    
    cursor.reset()
    for acct_id, asset in cursor:
        if not asset:
            try:
                asset = lookup[acct_id]
            except KeyError:
                print('No asset for "{}"'.format(acct_id))
            else:
                cursor.updateRow([acct_id, asset])
```

A second approach that doesn't involve looping over the table twice with a cursor is to use the DBMS engine to pre-sort the data when the cursor is instantiated, thus allowing a single pass over the table to make updates.

```py
fc = # path to feature class or table

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(
    fc, 
    ["ACCT_ID", "Asset"],
    sql_clause=(None, "ORDER BY ACCT_ID, Asset DESC")
) as cursor:
    prev_id, prev_asset = next(cursor)
    for cur_id, cur_asset in cursor:
        if cur_id == prev_id:
            cursor.updateRow([prev_id, prev_asset])
        else:
            prev_id, prev_asset = cur_id, cur_asset
```

Comment: "more efficient than instantiating multiple cursors"-- have you timed that or just based on assumption?  Iterating using an updatecursor could be slower than with a searchcursor (I don't know, genuinely curious)

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify it "can be" in "certain situations."  There are a lot of factors that determine whether it will be or not (e.g., back-end data source, number of records, size of records, amount of processing within the cursor loop, etc...), but I have had situations where it has been more efficient in terms of execution time.  That said, the reduction wasn't what I consider significant but more just noticeable.